# nested references in swagger file

Tags: python, swagger, openapi

My swagger.yml file contains references to separate files for parameters and schemas:

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
     $ref: 'http://servername/schemas.yml/#/User'
  parameters:
    email:
      $ref: 'http://servername/parameters.yml/#/email'
```

Example for the email parameter in the parameters.yml file:

```
email:
  name: "email"
  description: "email of a user"
  in: path
  required: True
  schema:
    type: "string"
```

My single_path_apis.yml file contains the different CRUD functions for my API calls:

```
user_by_email:
  get:
    operationId: "routes.users.fetch_user"
    tags:
      - Users
    summary: "Queries specific user in the database"
    parameters:
      - $ref: 'http://servername/parameters.yml/#/email'
    responses: 
      "200": 
        description: "Queried user"
```

In the swagger.yml file, I am importing the function above by using:

```
paths:
  /user/{email}:
    $ref: 'http://servername/single_path_apis.yml/#/user_by_email'
```

When I try to launch my app, i get following error: "path_parameters = (p for p in self.parameters if p["in"] == "path")".

This is happening for all path like "/path/{parameter}", but not with paths like "/path" (schemas get imported correctly, so not sure where it goes wrong with the parameters)...

When printing out the parameters that get read in, i get [{'$ref': 'http://servername/parameters.yml/#/email'}], so I think that the parameters are not getting parsed.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that loads and parses your swagger.yml file? What parser library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your uri's are incorrect

The `$ref` uri needs to have the `#` at the end of the filename and then you can reference the subschemas.

e.g.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    User:
     $ref: 'http://servername/schemas.yml#/User'
  parameters:
    email:
      $ref: 'http://servername/parameters.yml#/email'
```

Comment: Indeed, mistake on my side. I tried that but did not work either. I did manage to get everything working when pulling the files from S3 instead of the SFTP server